# Cannot get attachments in Outlook Calendar add-in

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

I am developing Microsoft Outlook Web Add-in, which is displayed in Calendar only. However, I cannot get appointment attachments using api: `Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments`, and the `attachments` object is undefined.
I would like to point out that in mail reading I can get attachments details without problems. This happens only in calendar.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide details? Which platform do you reproduce this, do you have a build number for that client?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, for testing I'm using Windows Desktop version 16.0.8528.2126 and outlook.com in Chrome

Comment: What are the permissions of your add-in? Which requirement set are you using? Just to clarify, when you say Calendar, you mean only Calendar Read mode?

Comment: My permissions are: `<Permissions>ReadItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>`
And I try to use add-in on appointment read. However every time I open appointment in Outlook it is open in edit mode (but its desided I guess).

Answer (score 2):

As mufeez mentioned above, `Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments` [is not supported in edit mode](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook&version=v1.5#attachments-arrayattachmentdetails).

Comment: So if I'm an organiser of a meeting can I somehow get access to attachments?

Answer (score 0):

/* Can you please try with below Code Snippet ,it's working in mycase for latest Outlook for Windows  16.0.8625.2121 ,i have `ReadWriteMailbox`  permissions for my add-ins which is not mandatory though ,it should work with `ReadItem` as well

/* Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments is not supported in edit mode i.e when you are a organizer of Appointment/Meeting */

/* ReadItem or ReadWriteItem or ReadWriteMailbox */
                        /* Get list of attachments */

```
var outputString = "";
for (i = 0; i < Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments.length; i++) {
     var _att = Office.context.mailbox.item.attachmen[i];
     outputString += "<BR>" + i + ". Name: ";
     outputString += _att.name;
     outputString += "<BR>ID: " + _att.id;
     outputString += "<BR>contentType: "+_att.contentType;
     outputString += "<BR>size: " + _att.size;
     outputString += "<BR>attachmentType: " + _att.attachmentType;
     outputString += "<BR>isInline: " + _att.isInline;
}
```

Comment: No, it does not work. As I write in my question, `attachments` object is unidentified, so I cannot iterate through it.

Comment: Seems like you are Organizer of this meeting/appointment ,which opens Calendar in edit mode and currently `Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments` is not Supported in edit mode

Comment: So there is no option to get the attachments as a organiser?

Comment: The best you can do is to save the item you're editing and then query  attachments using REST API.